# How to add templates to TeXmaker?

Tags: texmaker, templates, classicthesis, thesis

I´ll start my thesis and i found some nice templates here: [sharelatex](https://www.sharelatex.com/%E2%80%8E). By the way i dont get how to add the zip file of the template to teXmaker. Could anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: You probably have to unpack the zip file first and extract it contents to a folder, then open upload the template file(s) to sharelatex?

Comment: No. I mean i would like to use TeXMaker and i downloaded some thesis templates from shareLaTeX. I dont know where to extract the zip file which contains the template in order to use that template with texmaker. Im at OSX, any idea of how to solve this task?

Comment: IMHO there is no use of pushing the sharelatex templates to TeXmaker editor interface. You can always copy and paste the code snippets or files and open them with TeXmaker.

Answer (score 3):

If you extract the zip file to a folder then open the main.tex or whatever the main file is in TeXmaker it should automatically open the 'template' i.e. the structure will all be there.

Is this what you meant or did you mean to get TeXmaker to recognise it as a template in the Wizard menu (which is beyond me I'm afraid)?